# float has no attribute int , in python 3.2

Tags: python, random

I have this one error that says ,"float has no attribute int" error.
The question is to write a function that takes a parameter as image and draws two vertical lines to img, one red line from (50,0) to (50,300) and one made up of randomly colored pixels from (150,50) to (150,250). For some reason the random part, where I have randomcolor.int(0,255) is where I have the error. Is there something I need to convert? This is my code:

```
from cImage import*
import random
RandomColor = random.random()


myImWin = ImageWin("Line Image", 300, 300)
lineImage = EmptyImage(300,300)
redPixel = Pixel(255,0,0)
randomRed = Pixel(RandomColor.int(0,255))
for i in range(300):
    for x in range(250):
    lineImage.setPixel(50,i,redPixel)
    randomRed.setPixel(150,x,randomRed)
lineImage.draw(myImWin)
randomRed.save("lineImage.gif")
```

Any suggestions would help, thanks.

Comment: I'm curious, where did you get the idea that `.int(0,255)` would scale the value and convert it to an integer? I don't think I've seen that before in any context.

Comment: I meant to put randint but then i figured out later i should just put import random on the top, get rid of randomcolor = random.random(). then the area i have an error I should put random.randint(0,255),0,0). I forgot to put the 0,0, because in setPixels it accepts 3 values

Answer (score 6):

`random.random()` returns a random floating point in the range [0.0,1.0). If you wanted an integer of it, you'd have to do:

```
int(RandomColor) # would be 0 because random() is < 1.0
int(RandomColor * 256) # to get 0-255
```

You want a random number between 0-255, so couldn't you just do:

```
random.randint(0,255)
```

Comment: `int(RandomColor * 255)` will only get you a range from 0 to 254. +1 for `random.randint()`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker - Thanks for pointing that out about the `random()` range.

Answer (score 1):

`RandomColor` is the result of `random.random()`, and this is a `float`. If you want to get something between 0 and 255 from it, you should use `int(RandomColor*256)` or another more specific function of `random` module.

Comment: Nope, you need `int(RandomColor*256)`.

Comment: thank you everyone for your suggestions...Yes it makes sense to put as an integer, and having the number come out as float wouldn't make sense.